# Configuring Entrust CA cert for APNS on Websphere 6.1?

Tags: websphere, push-notification, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications, websphere-6.1

I'm running Websphere 6.1 on RHEL Linux. Trying to find out how to configure the APNS Entrust CA using the Websphere admin console key management commands. We are also using a proxy server outboud to connect to the Apple 17.0.0.0/8 push notification servers.
Thanks for any and all pointers/help on how to make ths work.

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) you both have to use a client SSL certificate and trust the server SSL certificate, correct?

In WebSphere 6.1, both are managed under:

`Security` > `SSL Certificate and Key Management` > `Key stores and certificates`

with the client certificate further under:

`xxxDefaultKeyStore` > `Personal certificates`

and the server certificate under:

`xxxDefaultTrustStore` > `Signer certificates`

For the client certificate, use the `Import` or `Receive` buttons. For the server, the easiest approach is the `Retrieve from port` button.

I confess that I haven't used client-side certificates under WAS before, so you might have additional configuration there, I expect under the `Security` > `SSL Certificate and Key Management` > `Dynamic outbound endpoint SSL configurations` page to explicitly specify use of your newly-imported client-side certificate when communicating with the APNS server(s).